# Create a string of unique ordered words in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a string column that has repeated words and in no particular order. I want to transform that column into a string of unique (distinct) words ordered alphabetically.

I've separated the words into arrays by splitting them (SPLIT) or by REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL (regexp = "\\w+"), but I could not figure out how to use distinct nor order them.

For example:

```
+-----------------------+
| Original              |
+-----------------------+
| blue sky, blue car    |
+-----------------------+
| pen pinapple pen      |
+-----------------------+


+-----------------------+
| Target                |
+-----------------------+
| blue car sky          |
+-----------------------+
| pinapple pen          |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: The best thing to do here would be to _normalize_ your CSV data before even bringing it into BigQuery.  If you were starting out with each word/term in a separate row, your life would be much easier.

Comment: I have done this with R, but I wanted to know if there is a simple way to do this in BigQuery SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can possibly do:

```sql
with data as (
    select 1 id, 'blue sky, blue car' text
    union all select 2, 'pen pineapple pen'
)
select id, 
       (select string_agg(distinct word, ' ' order by word) 
        from unnest(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(text, "\\w+")) word)
from data
```

Output:

```
+----+---------------+
| id |      f0_      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | blue car sky  |
|  2 | pen pineapple |
+----+---------------+
```